# How to call a json data in component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to render json data via a component but i think i am missing something

timetable.json

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "day": "Cumartesi",
      "events": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "start": "09:00",
          "end": "09:30",
          "event": "Toplanma ve Kahvaltı"
        },
...
```

App.js

```
const [timeTableData, setTimeTableData] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const tTableResult = await axios('./timetable.json')
      setTimeTableData(tTableResult.data.items[0])
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

Component.js

```
const { items } = props

   const listGroupItems = Object.keys(items.events).map((item) => {
        return (
          <CardBody key={item.key}>
            {item.start}
            {item.end}
            {item.event}
          </CardBody>
        )
    })
```

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access `items.events` before the data arrive. Check if it exists first

```
   const listGroupItems = items.events ? Object.keys(items.events).map((item) => {
        return (
          <CardBody key={item.key}>
            {item.start}
            {item.end}
            {item.event}
          </CardBody>
        )
    }) : null
```

Comment: its worked but there is still a problem. when i looked console.log(item) it gave me just 0,1,2,3..9 strings like events length

Comment: oook i got the problem. i was using Object.keys(items.event) instead of items.events.thanks for help thats really useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line

```
setTimeTableData(tTableResult.data.items[0])
```

Please remove `data` as it isn't defined in the JSON structure you mentioned. Hence, you might be getting `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: when you fetched something it always come with data object. that why using ..data..